# Upload multiple files to S3 using Lambda/Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

so I'm writing a Lambda function that is triggered by events from DynamoDB Streams, and I want to write these events to S3 (to create a data lake). but this code is only uploading the same json file. How can I upload multiple files into s3 without overwriting this one?

```
   import boto3
   import json
   
   s3 = boto3.client('s3')
   
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       
     bucket ='bto-history'
     dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
     tableUsers = dynamodb.Table('Users')
       
     jsonToUpload = event['Records']
   
     uploadFile = bytes(json.dumps(jsonToUpload).encode('UTF-8'))
     
     jsonToUpload = "userUpdate" + ".json"
   
     s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=jsonToUpload, Body=uploadFile)
   
     
     return {
       'statusCode': 200,
       'body': event
       }
```

Comment: FYI DynamoDB doesn't have files. It has tables, items, and attributes.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain **what you are wanting to accomplish?** For example, what triggers the Lambda function? What information are you wanting to store in S3? What do you want the key (filename) to be when it writes to S3?

Comment: Changed the question. I want the key to be a json file when it writes to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say, but I'm guessing that you are writing a Lambda function that is triggered by events from DynamoDB Streams, and you want to write those events to S3.

If you want to maintain multiple files/objects in S3 then you need to give them unique keys. Writing to userUpdate.json will simply overwrite any existing object with that key (unless you have versioning enabled, which I presume you don't).

So, create a unique object key each time. You could insert a timestamp in milliseconds (or other), which is probably unique. Or you could insert a UUID.

Worth asking: why do you want to store the DynamoDB Streams events in S3?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm working on a data lake that stores employees data, this data comes from a form. Btw, i have versioning enabled on my bucket.

Comment: OK, you can't update objects in S3, so your best bet is to log these DynamoDB events to unique objects in S3 (that could be unique filename of unique combination of folder+filename, both of which are actually keys, of course) or log them elsewhere (like CloudWatch Logs or an RDBMS).

Answer (score 0):

`event['Records']` is a list which you need to iterate over.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html

Each entry holds info about a dynamodb event.